# autofill pops up in chrome input unrelated to autofill

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, jquery-select2, autofill

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input select2-default" id="s2id_autogen2" placeholder="" style="width: 321px;" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-14">
```

This field has nothing to do with phone numbers.

When a user clicks on it, phone numbers try to autofill:

[image]

I tried clearing the cache but this happens on my machine and other user's as well.

How can I remove this erroneous autofill?

Answer (score 0):

It only happens to s2id_autogen2. It's definitely a bug.